# Django Caching - Not caching for certain part of the page

Tags: django, caching, memcached

I have a problem with django caching for login area using Safari.

When I use memcache and have 'django.middleware.cache.FetchFromCacheMiddleware' on, the login part of the page is always cached, showing "Welcome username" even after I press Logout.

It should change back to "login/sign up" link after logout is clicked. This seems to happen only in safari. Is there any way to not cache a part of the HTML page? I used @never_cache when it comes to view functions, but this login information is part of the base.html which gets extended throughout other site template htmls.

Thank you.

**Code**

In base.html

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
        <div class="login">
        <a id="login_dropdown_link" title="Login_nav">Welcome {{ user.username }} ( <span id="total_count"> {% total_count %}</span> )</a>
        </div>
{% else %}
        <div class="login">
        <span class="spaced"><a href="/accounts/login" id="login-link" class="red">Log In | Sign Up</a></span>
        </div>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: @never_cache is used on view functions, I don't understand what you mean by "view dependent HTML". Django has template fragment caching, but this sounds like a problem with your HTTP cache directives. HTTP-level caching happens on a per-request granularity - there's no way to say "don't cache *part* of this request", only "cache this request" or "don't cache this request".

Comment: Agree with @AdamKG. First thing to do would be to reexamine the base template that contains the login information -- is it cached there? Then confirm that the rest of the view *isn't* being cached, say by just adding `{% now "r" %}` which will show the current date and time of the request. You might want to add this to the login section of the base template as well!

Comment: Adam, I changed "view dependent HTML" to "view functions". That's what I meant.

Comment: Jordan, tried {% now "r" %} and seems like safari doesn't refresh the page, so it's causing this error. Other browsers such as Chrome and FF do refresh and changes the now time.

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely due to a header issue where Safari is being instructed to cache the page for a certain amount of time.